# Pagination doesn't work in query post in tag template

Tags: wordpress, post, pagination

In the tag template I used the following query post:

```
<?php

global $query_string; // required

$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$posts = query_posts($query_string . '&posts_per_page=5&cat=-93&paged=' . $paged);

if (have_posts()) :

    /* Start the Loop */
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();

        (content)
                endwhile;
endif;

wp_reset_query(); // reset the query 

the_posts_pagination(array('prev_text' => 'prev', 'next_text' => 'next'));
```

This is to have the post from the current tag but exclude one category and show 5 post per page. But this query post the navigation doesn't work.

I also added the string for 'paged' but nothing changes.

Can you help me?

Comment: the problem is navigation not show , or nav pagination  not linked to page 2/3 ?